# C# UDPClient accept any IP address

Tags: c#, network-programming, udp, hole-punching

I'm attempting to write a 3 way UDP hole punching application in C#. From what I've read, the steps are as follows.

1. Peer 1 Connects to Server
2. Server Notes IP Address and Port
3. Peer 2 Connects to Server and get Peer 1 details
4. Peer 2 Connects to Peer 1

What I have at the moment is Peer 1 is connecting to a server on port 8924, the server writes the remote IP Address and port details to a SQL database. Peer 2 connects to the Server and requests the details, Peer 2 then creates a new UDPClient and IPEndpoint using the details obtained. Everything seems to work up to this point, but when Peer 2 sends Data to Peer 1, nothing arrives.

There is no issue connecting Peer 1 -> Server, Server -> Peer 1, Peer 2 -> Server, Server -> Peer 2.

It looks to me as though Peer 1 will not accept messages from another IP Address, other than the Server.

The code below is fairly basic, but might give an idea where I'm going wrong. If anyone can hep out, I'd be grateful.

**Peer 1**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int command = 0;
        Random r = new Random();
        while (true)
        {
            UdpClient client = new UdpClient();
            IPEndPoint serverEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"), 8924);
            client.Connect(serverEndpoint);
            client.Send(BitConverter.GetBytes(command), 1);
            Task.Run(() => {
                byte[] data = client.Receive(ref serverEndpoint);
                Console.WriteLine(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
                Console.ReadLine();
            });
            Console.WriteLine("sleep");
            Thread.Sleep(30000);
            Console.WriteLine("resume");

        }

    }
```

**Peer 2**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("press enter to start");
            Console.ReadLine();
            UdpClient getDetailsClient = new UdpClient();
            IPEndPoint getDetailsEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"), 8924);
            getDetailsClient.Connect(getDetailsEndpoint);
            getDetailsClient.Send(BitConverter.GetBytes(1), 1);
            byte[] details = getDetailsClient.Receive(ref getDetailsEndpoint);
            byte[] bIp = new byte[15];
            int port = BitConverter.ToInt32(details, 0);
            Array.Copy(details, 4, bIp, 0, 15);
            string Ip = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bIp).Trim();
            Console.WriteLine($"Address: {Ip} \tPort: {port}");
            UdpClient peerClient = new UdpClient();
            IPEndPoint endpointClient = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(Ip), port);
            peerClient.Connect(endpointClient);
            peerClient.Send(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test"), 4);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
```

**Server**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int port =  8924;
        IPEndPoint remote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
        byte command;

        UdpClient server = new UdpClient(port);
        while(true)
        {
            //Wait on connection from client                
            var data = server.Receive(ref remote);
            //get command
            command = data[0];
            switch(command)
            {
                case (byte)0:
                    updateDatabase(ref server, ref remote);
                    break;
                case (byte)1:
                    readDatabase(ref server, ref remote);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }

    }

    private static void updateDatabase(ref UdpClient server, ref IPEndPoint remote)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write Command");
        using (dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext())
        {
            ConnectionTB tb = db.ConnectionTBs
                .Where(t => t.UniqueIdentifier.Trim().Equals("123456789"))
                .Select(t => t)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            tb.Port = remote.Port;
            tb.IPAddress = remote.Address.ToString();
            tb.LastPing = DateTime.Now;
            db.SubmitChanges();
            server.Send(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(remote.Address.ToString().PadRight(15)),15,remote);
        }
    }

    private static void readDatabase(ref UdpClient server, ref IPEndPoint remote)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Read Command");
        using (dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext())
        {
            ConnectionTB  p = db.ConnectionTBs
                .Where(c => c.UniqueIdentifier.Trim().Equals("123456789"))
                .Select(c => c)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            int port = p.Port.Value;
            string ip = p.IPAddress.Trim();
            byte[] data = new byte[19];
            byte[] bPort = BitConverter.GetBytes(port);
            byte[] bIp = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(p.IPAddress.PadRight(15));

            Array.Copy(bPort, 0, data, 0, 4);
            Array.Copy(bIp, 0, data, 4, 15);
            server.Send(data, 19, remote);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have never seen it before, so I will ask. What is IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx") doing? How do you actually provide an IP address to the endpoint? I believe the issue revolves around the fact you are using connected udp sockets.

Comment: @user_ABCD - It creates an IPAddress object from a string representation of a standard IP Address format e.g "192.168.1.1". I used 'x' to remove the actual IP address of my server.

Comment: HA, stupid me. I believe your best bet is to pass the ip & port directly to the connect call. Then create the endpoint before your client.Receive call and pass IPAddress.Any to it.

Answer (score 0):

@user_ABCD - It turns out you were correct. If I use Sockets instead of UDPCLient, I can "SendTo(EndPoint)" without binding, this allows me to change the IP Address / Port for the next send and all works as it should.

Thanks.